# JsonUtility.FromJson Cannot extract JSON data to string

Tags: json, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get data from a returned JSON result from REST API from my local host backend. I could get the value from name field but could not get the coord value. Are there any way to do so? Thanks!

The following is the results I got.

```
{
    "coord" : {
        "lon" : xxx.xxx,
        "lat" : xx.xxxx
    },
    "weather" : [
        {
            "id" : 801,
            "main" : "Clouds",
            "description" : "few clouds",
            "icon" : "02d"
        }
    ],
    "base" : "stations",
    "main" : { 
        "temp":23.04,
        "feels_like":22.89,
        "temp_min":21.83,
        "temp_max":24.52,
        "pressure":916,
        "humidity":57
    },
    "name" : "Ma Nam Wat"
}
```

My code:

```
public class GetMethod : MonoBehaviour
{
    public WeatherInfo Info;
    void GetData() => StartCoroutine(GetData_Coroutine() );
    IEnumerator GetData_Coroutine()
    {
        string uri = "http://localhost:3000/api/weather/current?lat=22.426522&lon=114.234446&unit=metric";
        using (UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Get(uri))
        {
            yield return request.SendWebRequest();
            if (request.isNetworkError || request.isHttpError)
                Debug.Log(request.error);
            else
                Debug.Log(request.downloadHandler.text);
            Info = JsonUtility.FromJson<WeatherInfo>(request.downloadHandler.text);
            Debug.Log(Info.coord.lon.ToString());
        }
    }

}
[SerializeField]
public class WeatherInfo
{
    public Coord coord;
    public string name;
}
[SerializeField]
public class Coord
{
    public float lon;
    public float lat;

}
```

Comment: "base" "name" ?? why not found in WeatherInfo ? it also in json

Comment: Your classes should have System.Serializable attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You confused the attribute [`[SerializeField]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html) which is for serializing a non-public field with [`[System.Serializable]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.serializableattribute) which is for marking a type serializable ;)

```
[Serializable]
public class WeatherInfo
{
    public Coord coord;
    public string name;
}

[Serializable]
public class Coord
{
    public float lon;
    public float lat;
}
```